# Why is justify-content placing things on the bottom? Am I doing something wrong in my css?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, padding, justify

I'm not very good at html,css,twcss. I need help.
Whenever I use `justify-contents:space-between;` it moves some things down.
An image of my problem
[justify acting wierd or my skill issue?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3VvX.png)
The following is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro">
    <title>./T3RM1N4L</title>
  </head>
  <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover" onloa>
    <div style="display: contents">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"></script>
      <script>
        eruda.init();
      </script>
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center my-12 mx-2 flex-col">
          <div class="text-5xl m-2">./T3RM1N4L</div>
          <div class="border h-[8 rem] overflow-y-auto rounded-md snap-y" style="width: 800px">

            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="19" width="19" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M0 96C0 60.7 28.7 32 64 32H196.1c19.1 0 37.4 7.6 50.9 21.1L289.9 96H448c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64V416c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V96zM64 80c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V416c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16H448c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V160c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16H286.6c-10.6 0-20.8-4.2-28.3-11.7L213.1 87c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H64z" />
                  </svg>  
              <a style="justify-content: start; right: auto !important; padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 29rem; " href="./AnuraOSessentials/index.html">AnuraOS</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10" >18/09/2022</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1" >major </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="19" width="19" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M0 96C0 60.7 28.7 32 64 32H196.1c19.1 0 37.4 7.6 50.9 21.1L289.9 96H448c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64V416c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V96zM64 80c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V416c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16H448c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V160c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16H286.6c-10.6 0-20.8-4.2-28.3-11.7L213.1 87c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H64z" />
                  </svg>  
              <a style="justify-content: start; right: auto !important; padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 30.25rem; " href="./ASCII/index.html">ASCII</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">24/11/2022</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">minor </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex items-center">
                 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="19" width="19" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M0 96C0 60.7 28.7 32 64 32H196.1c19.1 0 37.4 7.6 50.9 21.1L289.9 96H448c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64V416c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V96zM64 80c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V416c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16H448c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V160c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16H286.6c-10.6 0-20.8-4.2-28.3-11.7L213.1 87c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H64z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div style="justify-content: space-between;">  
                <a style="padding-left: 1rem;" href="./education/index.html">Education</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">26/04/2023</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1" >major </div>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./Emulation/index.html">Emulation</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">18/10/2023</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">major </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./H4cks/index.html">H4cks</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">current </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./Images/index.html">Images</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">latest </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./Important_MarkDowns/index.html">Important_MarkDowns</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">latest </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./sedoms/index.html">Sedoms</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">latest </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./uhruhruhr/index.html">uhruhruhr</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">latest </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-sm font-thin italic">scroll</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        *,
        :before,
        :after {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border-width: 0;
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: #e5e7eb;
          font-family: "Source Code Pro", sans-serif !important;
        }

        :before,
        :after {
          --tw-content: ""
        }

        body {
          background-color: black !important;
          color: white !important;
        }

        html {
          line-height: 1.5;
          -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
          -moz-tab-size: 4;
          -o-tab-size: 4;
          tab-size: 4;
          font-family: Inter, ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, Noto Sans, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", Segoe UI Symbol, "Noto Color Emoji";
          font-feature-settings: normal;
          font-variation-settings: normal
        }

        body {
          margin: 0;
          line-height: inherit
        }

        hr {
          height: 0;
          color: inherit;
          border-top-width: 1px
        }

        abbr:where([title]) {
          -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6 {
          font-size: inherit;
          font-weight: inherit
        }

        a {
          color: inherit;
          text-decoration: inherit;
        }

        b,
        strong {
          font-weight: bolder
        }

        code,
        kbd,
        samp,
        pre {
          font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, Liberation Mono, Courier New, monospace;
          font-size: 1em
        }

        small {
          font-size: 80%
        }

        sub,
        sup {
          font-size: 75%;
          line-height: 0;
          position: relative;
          vertical-align: baseline
        }

        sub {
          bottom: -.25em
        }

        sup {
          top: -.5em
        }

        table {
          text-indent: 0;
          border-color: inherit;
          border-collapse: collapse
        }

        button,
        input,
        optgroup,
        select,
        textarea {
          font-family: inherit;
          font-size: 100%;
          font-weight: inherit;
          line-height: inherit;
          color: inherit;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0
        }

        button,
        select {
          text-transform: none
        }

        button,
        [type=button],
        [type=reset],
        [type=submit] {
          appearance: button;
          background-color: transparent;
          background-image: none
        }

        :-moz-focusring {
          outline: auto
        }

        :-moz-ui-invalid {
          box-shadow: none
        }

        progress {
          vertical-align: baseline
        }

        ::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
          height: auto
        }

        [type=search] {
          -webkit-appearance: textfield;
          outline-offset: -2px
        }

        ::-webkit-search-decoration {
          -webkit-appearance: none
        }

        ::-webkit-file-upload-button {
          -webkit-appearance: button;
          font: inherit
        }

        summary {
          display: list-item
        }

        blockquote,
        dl,
        dd,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6,
        hr,
        figure,
        p,
        pre {
          margin: 0
        }

        fieldset {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0
        }

        legend {
          padding: 0
        }

        ol,
        ul,
        menu {
          list-style: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0
        }

        textarea {
          resize: vertical
        }

        input::-moz-placeholder,
        textarea::-moz-placeholder {
          opacity: 1;
          color: #9ca3af
        }

        input::placeholder,
        textarea::placeholder {
          opacity: 1;
          color: #9ca3af
        }

        button,
        [role=button] {
          cursor: pointer
        }

        :disabled {
          cursor: default
        }

        img,
        svg,
        video,
        canvas,
        audio,
        iframe,
        embed,
        object {
          display: block;
          vertical-align: middle
        }

        img,
        video {
          max-width: 100%;
          height: auto
        }

        [hidden] {
          display: none
        }

        *,
        :before,
        :after {
          --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
          --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
          --tw-translate-x: 0;
          --tw-translate-y: 0;
          --tw-rotate: 0;
          --tw-skew-x: 0;
          --tw-skew-y: 0;
          --tw-scale-x: 1;
          --tw-scale-y: 1;
          --tw-pan-x: ;
          --tw-pan-y: ;
          --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
          --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
          --tw-gradient-from-position: ;
          --tw-gradient-via-position: ;
          --tw-gradient-to-position: ;
          --tw-ordinal: ;
          --tw-slashed-zero: ;
          --tw-numeric-figure: ;
          --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
          --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
          --tw-ring-inset: ;
          --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
          --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
          --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / .5);
          --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-blur: ;
          --tw-brightness: ;
          --tw-contrast: ;
          --tw-grayscale: ;
          --tw-hue-rotate: ;
          --tw-invert: ;
          --tw-saturate: ;
          --tw-sepia: ;
          --tw-drop-shadow: ;
          --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
          --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
          --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
          --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
          --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
          --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
          --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
          --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
          --tw-backdrop-sepia:
        }

        ::backdrop {
          --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
          --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
          --tw-translate-x: 0;
          --tw-translate-y: 0;
          --tw-rotate: 0;
          --tw-skew-x: 0;
          --tw-skew-y: 0;
          --tw-scale-x: 1;
          --tw-scale-y: 1;
          --tw-pan-x: ;
          --tw-pan-y: ;
          --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
          --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
          --tw-gradient-from-position: ;
          --tw-gradient-via-position: ;
          --tw-gradient-to-position: ;
          --tw-ordinal: ;
          --tw-slashed-zero: ;
          --tw-numeric-figure: ;
          --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
          --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
          --tw-ring-inset: ;
          --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
          --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
          --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / .5);
          --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-blur: ;
          --tw-brightness: ;
          --tw-contrast: ;
          --tw-grayscale: ;
          --tw-hue-rotate: ;
          --tw-invert: ;
          --tw-saturate: ;
          --tw-sepia: ;
          --tw-drop-shadow: ;
          --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
          --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
          --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
          --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
          --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
          --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
          --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
          --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
          --tw-backdrop-sepia:
        }

        .m-1 {
          margin: .25rem
        }

        .m-2 {
          margin: .5rem
        }

        .mx-2 {
          margin-left: .5rem;
          margin-right: .5rem
        }

        .my-12 {
          margin-top: 3rem;
          margin-bottom: 3rem
        }

        .ml-10 {
          margin-left: 2.5rem
        }

        .flex {
          display: flex
        }

        .contents {
          display: contents
        }

        .h-\[3\.5rem\] {
          height: 3.5rem
        }

        .cursor-pointer {
          cursor: pointer
        }

        .snap-y {
          scroll-snap-type: y var(--tw-scroll-snap-strictness)
        }

        .snap-center {
          scroll-snap-align: center
        }

        .flex-row {
          flex-direction: row
        }

        .flex-col {
          flex-direction: column
        }

        .items-center {
          align-items: center
        }

        .justify-center {
          justify-content: center
        }

        .justify-between {
          justify-content: space-between
        }

        .gap-2 {
          gap: .5rem
        }

        .overflow-y-auto {
          overflow-y: auto
        }

        .rounded-md {
          border-radius: .375rem
        }

        .border {
          border-width: 1px
        }

        .bg-gray-400 {
          --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
          background-color: rgb(156 163 175 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
        }

        .bg-slate-200 {
          --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
          background-color: rgb(21 21 23 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
        }

        .p-1 {
          padding: .25rem
        }

        .p-2 {
          padding: .5rem
        }

        .font-sans {
          font-family: Inter, ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, Noto Sans, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", Segoe UI Symbol, "Noto Color Emoji"
        }

        .text-5xl {
          font-size: 3rem;
          line-height: 1
        }

        .text-sm {
          font-size: .875rem;
          line-height: 1.25rem
        }

        .font-thin {
          font-weight: 100
        }

        .italic {
          font-style: italic
        }

        .text-slate-400 {
          --tw-text-opacity: 1;
          color: rgb(148 163 184 / var(--tw-text-opacity))
        }

        .text-white {
          --tw-text-opacity: 1;
          color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))
        }

        .hover\:border-slate-400:hover {
          --tw-border-opacity: 1;
          border-color: rgb(148, 163, 184 / var(--tw-border-opacity))
        }

        .hover\:bg-slate-300:hover {
          --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
          background-color: rgb(171, 203, 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
        }
      </style>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>       </style>
 
 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried messing around with padding, but I have to have a specific padding for each one. If I add justify content to one of the parent divs, it works, but the folder svg is at the left. I kind of want to make it look like github repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `display: flex` property for `justify-content: space-between` to work.

I also added a width: 100% to ensure that the flex container spans the full width of its parent element.

```
                  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 100%;">  
                    <a style="padding-left: 1rem;" href="./education/index.html">Education</a>
                    <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                      <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">26/04/2023</div>
                      <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1" >major </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the elements have `block` as default `display`, so it don't have sub-properties of `flex display` like `justify-content`.
To have the effect set `display: flex` with `justify-content: space-between`.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro">
    <title>./T3RM1N4L</title>
  </head>
  <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover" onloa>
    <div style="display: contents">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"></script>
      <script>
        eruda.init();
      </script>
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center my-12 mx-2 flex-col">
          <div class="text-5xl m-2">./T3RM1N4L</div>
          <div class="border h-[8 rem] overflow-y-auto rounded-md snap-y" style="width: 800px">

            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="19" width="19" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M0 96C0 60.7 28.7 32 64 32H196.1c19.1 0 37.4 7.6 50.9 21.1L289.9 96H448c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64V416c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V96zM64 80c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V416c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16H448c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V160c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16H286.6c-10.6 0-20.8-4.2-28.3-11.7L213.1 87c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H64z" />
                  </svg>  
              <a style="justify-content: start; right: auto !important; padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 29rem; " href="./AnuraOSessentials/index.html">AnuraOS</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10" >18/09/2022</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1" >major </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="19" width="19" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M0 96C0 60.7 28.7 32 64 32H196.1c19.1 0 37.4 7.6 50.9 21.1L289.9 96H448c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64V416c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V96zM64 80c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V416c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16H448c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V160c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16H286.6c-10.6 0-20.8-4.2-28.3-11.7L213.1 87c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H64z" />
                  </svg>  
              <a style="justify-content: start; right: auto !important; padding-left: 1rem; padding-right: 30.25rem; " href="./ASCII/index.html">ASCII</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">24/11/2022</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">minor </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex items-center">
                 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="19" width="19" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M0 96C0 60.7 28.7 32 64 32H196.1c19.1 0 37.4 7.6 50.9 21.1L289.9 96H448c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64V416c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V96zM64 80c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V416c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16H448c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V160c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16H286.6c-10.6 0-20.8-4.2-28.3-11.7L213.1 87c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H64z" />
                  </svg>
                  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">  
                <a style="padding-left: 1rem;" href="./education/index.html">Education</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">26/04/2023</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1" >major </div>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./Emulation/index.html">Emulation</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">18/10/2023</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">major </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./H4cks/index.html">H4cks</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">current </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./Images/index.html">Images</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">latest </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./Important_MarkDowns/index.html">Important_MarkDowns</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">latest </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./sedoms/index.html">Sedoms</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">latest </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="snap-center p-2 border rounded-md m-1 bg-slate-200 hover:bg-slate-300 cursor-pointer font-sans hover:border-slate-400 flex-row flex justify-between items-center">
              <a href="./uhruhruhr/index.html">uhruhruhr</a>
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                <div class="text-slate-400 ml-10">00/00/0000</div>
                <div class="text-sm bg-gray-400 rounded-md text-white p-1">latest </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-sm font-thin italic">scroll</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        *,
        :before,
        :after {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border-width: 0;
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: #e5e7eb;
          font-family: "Source Code Pro", sans-serif !important;
        }

        :before,
        :after {
          --tw-content: ""
        }

        body {
          background-color: black !important;
          color: white !important;
        }

        html {
          line-height: 1.5;
          -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
          -moz-tab-size: 4;
          -o-tab-size: 4;
          tab-size: 4;
          font-family: Inter, ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, Noto Sans, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", Segoe UI Symbol, "Noto Color Emoji";
          font-feature-settings: normal;
          font-variation-settings: normal
        }

        body {
          margin: 0;
          line-height: inherit
        }

        hr {
          height: 0;
          color: inherit;
          border-top-width: 1px
        }

        abbr:where([title]) {
          -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6 {
          font-size: inherit;
          font-weight: inherit
        }

        a {
          color: inherit;
          text-decoration: inherit;
        }

        b,
        strong {
          font-weight: bolder
        }

        code,
        kbd,
        samp,
        pre {
          font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, Liberation Mono, Courier New, monospace;
          font-size: 1em
        }

        small {
          font-size: 80%
        }

        sub,
        sup {
          font-size: 75%;
          line-height: 0;
          position: relative;
          vertical-align: baseline
        }

        sub {
          bottom: -.25em
        }

        sup {
          top: -.5em
        }

        table {
          text-indent: 0;
          border-color: inherit;
          border-collapse: collapse
        }

        button,
        input,
        optgroup,
        select,
        textarea {
          font-family: inherit;
          font-size: 100%;
          font-weight: inherit;
          line-height: inherit;
          color: inherit;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0
        }

        button,
        select {
          text-transform: none
        }

        button,
        [type=button],
        [type=reset],
        [type=submit] {
          appearance: button;
          background-color: transparent;
          background-image: none
        }

        :-moz-focusring {
          outline: auto
        }

        :-moz-ui-invalid {
          box-shadow: none
        }

        progress {
          vertical-align: baseline
        }

        ::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
          height: auto
        }

        [type=search] {
          -webkit-appearance: textfield;
          outline-offset: -2px
        }

        ::-webkit-search-decoration {
          -webkit-appearance: none
        }

        ::-webkit-file-upload-button {
          -webkit-appearance: button;
          font: inherit
        }

        summary {
          display: list-item
        }

        blockquote,
        dl,
        dd,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6,
        hr,
        figure,
        p,
        pre {
          margin: 0
        }

        fieldset {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0
        }

        legend {
          padding: 0
        }

        ol,
        ul,
        menu {
          list-style: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0
        }

        textarea {
          resize: vertical
        }

        input::-moz-placeholder,
        textarea::-moz-placeholder {
          opacity: 1;
          color: #9ca3af
        }

        input::placeholder,
        textarea::placeholder {
          opacity: 1;
          color: #9ca3af
        }

        button,
        [role=button] {
          cursor: pointer
        }

        :disabled {
          cursor: default
        }

        img,
        svg,
        video,
        canvas,
        audio,
        iframe,
        embed,
        object {
          display: block;
          vertical-align: middle
        }

        img,
        video {
          max-width: 100%;
          height: auto
        }

        [hidden] {
          display: none
        }

        *,
        :before,
        :after {
          --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
          --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
          --tw-translate-x: 0;
          --tw-translate-y: 0;
          --tw-rotate: 0;
          --tw-skew-x: 0;
          --tw-skew-y: 0;
          --tw-scale-x: 1;
          --tw-scale-y: 1;
          --tw-pan-x: ;
          --tw-pan-y: ;
          --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
          --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
          --tw-gradient-from-position: ;
          --tw-gradient-via-position: ;
          --tw-gradient-to-position: ;
          --tw-ordinal: ;
          --tw-slashed-zero: ;
          --tw-numeric-figure: ;
          --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
          --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
          --tw-ring-inset: ;
          --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
          --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
          --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / .5);
          --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-blur: ;
          --tw-brightness: ;
          --tw-contrast: ;
          --tw-grayscale: ;
          --tw-hue-rotate: ;
          --tw-invert: ;
          --tw-saturate: ;
          --tw-sepia: ;
          --tw-drop-shadow: ;
          --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
          --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
          --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
          --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
          --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
          --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
          --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
          --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
          --tw-backdrop-sepia:
        }

        ::backdrop {
          --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
          --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
          --tw-translate-x: 0;
          --tw-translate-y: 0;
          --tw-rotate: 0;
          --tw-skew-x: 0;
          --tw-skew-y: 0;
          --tw-scale-x: 1;
          --tw-scale-y: 1;
          --tw-pan-x: ;
          --tw-pan-y: ;
          --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
          --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
          --tw-gradient-from-position: ;
          --tw-gradient-via-position: ;
          --tw-gradient-to-position: ;
          --tw-ordinal: ;
          --tw-slashed-zero: ;
          --tw-numeric-figure: ;
          --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
          --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
          --tw-ring-inset: ;
          --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
          --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
          --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / .5);
          --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
          --tw-blur: ;
          --tw-brightness: ;
          --tw-contrast: ;
          --tw-grayscale: ;
          --tw-hue-rotate: ;
          --tw-invert: ;
          --tw-saturate: ;
          --tw-sepia: ;
          --tw-drop-shadow: ;
          --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
          --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
          --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
          --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
          --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
          --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
          --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
          --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
          --tw-backdrop-sepia:
        }

        .m-1 {
          margin: .25rem
        }

        .m-2 {
          margin: .5rem
        }

        .mx-2 {
          margin-left: .5rem;
          margin-right: .5rem
        }

        .my-12 {
          margin-top: 3rem;
          margin-bottom: 3rem
        }

        .ml-10 {
          margin-left: 2.5rem
        }

        .flex {
          display: flex
        }

        .contents {
          display: contents
        }

        .h-\[3\.5rem\] {
          height: 3.5rem
        }

        .cursor-pointer {
          cursor: pointer
        }

        .snap-y {
          scroll-snap-type: y var(--tw-scroll-snap-strictness)
        }

        .snap-center {
          scroll-snap-align: center
        }

        .flex-row {
          flex-direction: row
        }

        .flex-col {
          flex-direction: column
        }

        .items-center {
          align-items: center
        }

        .justify-center {
          justify-content: center
        }

        .justify-between {
          justify-content: space-between
        }

        .gap-2 {
          gap: .5rem
        }

        .overflow-y-auto {
          overflow-y: auto
        }

        .rounded-md {
          border-radius: .375rem
        }

        .border {
          border-width: 1px
        }

        .bg-gray-400 {
          --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
          background-color: rgb(156 163 175 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
        }

        .bg-slate-200 {
          --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
          background-color: rgb(21 21 23 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
        }

        .p-1 {
          padding: .25rem
        }

        .p-2 {
          padding: .5rem
        }

        .font-sans {
          font-family: Inter, ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, Noto Sans, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", Segoe UI Symbol, "Noto Color Emoji"
        }

        .text-5xl {
          font-size: 3rem;
          line-height: 1
        }

        .text-sm {
          font-size: .875rem;
          line-height: 1.25rem
        }

        .font-thin {
          font-weight: 100
        }

        .italic {
          font-style: italic
        }

        .text-slate-400 {
          --tw-text-opacity: 1;
          color: rgb(148 163 184 / var(--tw-text-opacity))
        }

        .text-white {
          --tw-text-opacity: 1;
          color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))
        }

        .hover\:border-slate-400:hover {
          --tw-border-opacity: 1;
          border-color: rgb(148, 163, 184 / var(--tw-border-opacity))
        }

        .hover\:bg-slate-300:hover {
          --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
          background-color: rgb(171, 203, 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
        }
      </style>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>       </style>
 
 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```